# Putting a graphical frame/border around a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've a few tables in my app. At the moment they are a plain standard transparent table.
You can see the background image behind the table and thats ok.

Put the table looks strange and maybe out of place because it is not obvious its a table.

Is there some option( i couldnt find any) for adding a frame/boarder(like a picture frame) around the table that the table can scroll inside of? I've searched though table and didnt see any.

So if thats true then that leaves me needing to draw a graphic over the table so that the table appears inside it. Any advise welcome.

EDIT:

```
CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(30, 50, 270, 350);
table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct 
 style:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
table.layer.borderWidth = 5;
table.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
table.dataSource = self;
table.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:table];
```

Added this code and the import of Quartz.

But no boarder was drawn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use its layers' properties:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Note that this does not cause the table to actually shrink in size to accomodate the border's width as you might expect, so depending on your `borderWidth` it will draw over some content of the table.

Comment: Added the code above in the EDIT of the question. But no boarder was drawn. Is there something i am missing?

Comment: it seems correct... as Flash84x suggests, maybe is too large or the border is hidden by other view or the window limits?

Comment: Well since the table background is transparent it cant be hidding the boarder it it was drawing. Since the layer belongs to the table, making the table smaller it not going to change anything. I messed around with things but the boarder is not appearing. -.- Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Hey! It is working but this border / frame is to much simple. Do you know how I can add effect like the grouped UITableView? I am thinking doubt this glitter around the frame. I think I have to add effect like in Photoshop Bevel and Emboss effect, but how can I add it with help of CALayer and CIFilter?

Answer (score 1):

You could also make the tableview smaller on all sides and the have that sit on an image of a frame.